Tcolorbox, "breakable" unrecognized
This should be a MRE:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=green!5!white, boxrule=0.5mm, sharp corners}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, title=Svolgimento]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


When loading tcolorbox with \usepackage{tcolorbox}, you are not loading all of the package's libraries. In particular, you are not loading the breakable library, which is responsible for the breakable option in boxes.
To load the breakable library, you can either load it with the package with
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

or you can load it separately with
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

See sections 1.2 and 1.3 of the documentation for more details.
Here's a complete example.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=green!5!white, boxrule=0.5mm, sharp corners}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, title=Svolgimento]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}



Vincent has already answered.
I would only add that, instead of loading every single library you need, you could use one of the three shortcuts to load some or all of them at once: many, which loads the libraries for the box settings; most, which loads all libraries except minted and documentation; and all that loads all libraries.
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

For details, see Section 1.3 Libraries of the package documentation or prof. van Duck's article about tcolorbox.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mwe}%<-- for testing purpose only

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=green!5!white, boxrule=0.5mm, sharp corners}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, title=Svolgimento]
\blindtext[7]%<-- for testing purpose only
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


